# Using COM With C

Tags: c, com

I'm having issues using COM from a C program, when I call functions on an object I get

`Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.`

Which suggests somehow I'm using the wrong calling convention, but not sure how I diagnose or fix this issue.

Here's the code I wrote to test this:

```
#include <shlobj.h>

int main()
{
    IProgressDialog* dialog = NULL;

    HRESULT hr = 0;
    hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_ProgressDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IProgressDialog, &dialog);

    hr = dialog->lpVtbl->SetTitle(dialog, L"Progress"); // this line causes the run time check failure
```

I'm using VS2019 for this, if that matters.
Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: you checked those `hr` results the posted code is ignoring, *right* ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I'm stepping through with the debugger and inspecting its value.

Comment: @Joe I just copied this in verbatim (adding the closing `}`) and punched it through VS2015 SP1 without issue.`S_OK` returned on all calls. The calling convention is established by the `STDMETHOD` decl of the member, so I can't see how that's boning you here.

Comment: @HansPassant Windows SDK version 10.0.18362.0, toolset v142.shlobj.h itself doesn't check for C (I think?), but combaseapi.h has a different definition of STDMETHOD for C:
`#define STDMETHOD(method)       HRESULT (STDMETHODCALLTYPE * method)`

Comment: @WhozCraig that's odd, so I guess it's something broken by VS17 or 19?

Comment: Fwiw, I'm using Windows kit 8.1. @HansPassant, in case you don't have that handy (which I'd be shocked), the decl is pretty straight up [here it is](https://pastebin.com/8BsJAC9v). The macros map to what I would expect for a C interface client when compiled as C. `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` is, in fact, `__stdcall`. Odd that I have no issue with this.

Comment: @Mathieu The tag you added is not appropriate here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are right, sorry, I read too fast.

Comment: Okay, I'm too used to seeing the MIDL output.  This is a bunch of macaroni, best thing to do is to look at the preprocessed file.  Use Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor, "Preprocess to a file".  Compile and look at the generated .i file, search for IProgressDialog.  With the expectation that it is no longer the 3rd function (unlikely) or that `__stdcall` got lost somehow.

Comment: @HansPassant what a good idea, I'll try that

Comment: @HansPassant https://pastebin.com/HNx6cZUs doesn't look like it...

Comment: It doesn't.  If you checked the call as well then next use the debugger to step into this function to see in what DLL it ends up.  Might be an evil one.

Comment: @HansPassant for some reason I can't get the debugger to step into the function.. I've unticked "just my code", but it still doesn't want to do it..

Comment: Be sure to do this while you are in the Debug > Windows > Disassembly window.

Comment: @HansPassant nice one - so I followed the call into shell32.dll, and ntdll.dll, at which point I remembered loading symbols for those would be a good idea, and look what I see in the vtable of my dialog https://pastebin.com/MMV9ajhF
So the vtable itself is totally wrong, very strange...

Comment: Well, ugh.  See what happens when you ask for IID_IUnknown and then QueryInterface for IID_IProgressDialog.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried this:
```CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_ProgressDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IUnknown, &unk);
unk->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(unk, &IID_IProgressDialog, &dialog);```
Same result :(